# Need to bundle specific exe files and other files into one executable file

Tags: c++, exe, executable

My problem is quite simple.

I have multiple exe files and a config file in JSON which provides the parameters for execution to the exe files.

What I want to do is to bundle all of these into a single executable (including the json), hence preventing the user from modifying or seeing the json file or its contents.

The user would just execute the single exe and everything will be done.

I'm new to this and I couldn't find any production quality way to do this.

Comment: The simple answer is write a new program which does that. The json text would be a string literal. Note that this defeats the purpose of having a config file. The fancy answer would involve encryption, so they have to use a json file you create and sign. If they agree to all this ... good luck. :)

Comment: If it's licensing keys, look for that specifically.

Comment: Note that it's quite easy to examine the contents of an executable to find a string literal and read that.  On Posix, the `strings` command will do it for you.

Comment: @KennyOstrom  It is not licensing keys but a remote desktop connection applet. The config file is nothing but the info required to connect to the specific users system. It is for support of another software.

Comment: Ah, then you need encryption, or (better) just make them type in the password when they connect. All this about hiding the json is useless as Martin Bonner pointed out. Alternatively, look into authentication by keypair (so they only need to know their own key's password, not the password of every system they connect to).